# How to find out my host for fileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

I just bought a new domain and now i want to upload files there.

I am trying to use FileZilla and it  asks me for Host,Username,Password and Port.

Now in Username and Password i have tried typing the same things i typed in GoDaddy.com, but now i do not know what to type in Host and Port.
By the way are there any other easier and free ways to upload files to my website?

Comment: You bought a domain or a webhotel/simlar? If you only bought a domain, do you actually *have* a server to upload to? A domain alone is just a name, somewhere in the world there has to be a server this name maps to. So what exactly did you buy? If you bought a webhotel or similar, then the website where you manage your webhotel will/should be able to tell you all those details easily.

Comment: Yes i only bought domain form godaddy.And how can i find a server to upload it?

Comment: Then you need to rent a server somewhere, there's plenty of sites where you can do this. Google for server rent, they can be called VPS (virtual private server), webhotel, "rented server", etc. Also, if you only plan on hosting a website, you might not need a "whole server", you may only need to rent space for your website on an existing server. Again, google is your friend.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Should i also buy it on godaddy or other websites are OK?

Comment: Any website that has a fixed ip should be ok.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you bought a domain or some kind of hosting service?

A domain is only a name, you cannot host files there.

FileZilla should be very easy to use once set up, so that's not going to be your issue.

Comment: I have bought Only Domain

Comment: Then you also need so buy/rent a file server of some kind, what you bought is only a name that can be used to direct people to that server. Right now it probably points to nowhere or some default server.

Comment: Thanks for you answer:)